# How to convert DataFrame or RDD[object] to Array[Object] in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am currently using `spark streaming` and `spark sql` for my current project. Is there a way to convert `Array[Object]` to either `RDD[object]` or `DataFrame`? I am doing something as below:

```
val myData = myDf.distinct()
                 .collect()
                 .map{ row => 
                   new myObject(row.getAs[String]("id"), row.getAs[String]("name"))
                 }
```

The myData on the code snippet above will be `Array[myObject]`. How to I make it to `RDD[myObject]` or directly to `DataFrame` for next execution?

Comment: remove the call to `collect`

Comment: @TonTorres by removing the collect, yes it returns RDD[myObject]. But it does not run the .map function anymore which does not serve the purpose.

Comment: `RDD`s and `DataFrame`s also have a `map` function

Comment: @TonTorres Ya it can run in this way too. it runs the map function. Thanks for the solution, :)

Comment: The headline is the reverse of the code of the question and the accepted answer. You already have a DataFrame; you want to create an Array[Object].
(Edit: Turns out, I haz the power to edit the heading, so I did that!)

Comment: @JonWatte I don't think that's right. Deric has a dataframe, and wants to get distinct values, and strongly-type select two of the columns, and return a dataframe (or RDD). The problem was that the code was returning Array[myObject] so not useful in further spark processing. Ton Torres' answer below does that perfectly. Takes myDF and returns myData, as a strongly typed (yay!) dataset, not a dataframe.

Comment: @Davos May The problem I was talking about was an incorrect heading. The heading initially sounded like it was asking how to go from Array to DataFrame.

Comment: @JonWatte I think the heading you've changed it to is wrong. In the last sentence Deric he says clearly that the myData val is an Array[Object] and wants to 'make it to RDD or directly to DataFrame'.  He is not asking to convert it to an Array, he's already got an array. The original heading 'how to go from Array to DataFrame' is consistent with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class myObject(id:String, name:String)

val myData = myDf.distinct.map {
  case Row(id:String, name:String) => myObject(id,name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I get to parse it to RDD[myObject]. I hope is the right way to do it.

```
val myData = myDf.distinct()
             .collect()
             .map{ row => 
               new myObject(row.getAs[String]("id"), row.getAs[String]("name"))
             }
val myDataRDD = rdd.SparkContext.parallelize(myData) // since this code snippet is inside a foreachRDD clause.
```